# Delphi 5 - Catch all exceptions with RTLUnwind

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-5

I'm here today because i've got some troubles trying to catch every exceptions of my program using Delphi 5 and the RTLUnwind.

The problem is that it catch an error, but it close my program immediatly after ...
When i'm trying to debugging, there is access violation that appearing.

Here is my whole code for this catch :

```
unit ExceptLog;

interface

implementation

uses SysUtils, Windows, U_Test, Dialogs;

type
  PCardinal = ^Cardinal;
  PtrUInt = cardinal;
  PPtrUInt = ^PtrUInt;
  PExceptionRecord = ^TExceptionRecord;
  TExceptionRecord =
  record
    ExceptionCode : LongWord;
    ExceptionFlags : LongWord;
    OuterException : PExceptionRecord;
    ExceptionAddress : Pointer;
    NumberParameters : Longint;
    case {IsOsException:} Boolean of
    True : (ExceptionInformation : array [0..14] of Longint);
    False : (ExceptAddr: Pointer; ExceptObject: Pointer);
  end;

var
  // Declaration for Delphi 5
  oldRTLUnwindProc: procedure; stdcall;
  RTLUnWindProc: pointer;

procedure MyRtlUnwind; stdcall;
var
  s : string;
  PER : PExceptionRecord;
  E: Exception;
begin
  asm
    mov eax, dword ptr [EBP+8+13*4]
    mov PER, eax
  end;

  if PER^.ExceptionFlags and 1=1 then
  begin
    try
      E := Exception(PER^.ExceptObject);
      if (E is Exception) then
      begin
        s:= 'Delphi exception, type : ' + E.ClassName + ', message: ' +     E.Message;
        OutputDebugString(PChar(s));

        _MessageDlg(s, mtInformation, [mbOk], 0);
      end;
    except
    end;
  end;

  asm
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    jmp oldRTLUnwindProc  // here come the access violation
  end;
end;

{--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure PatchCodePtrUInt(Code: PPtrUInt; Value: PtrUInt);
var RestoreProtection, Ignore: DWORD;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(Code, SizeOf(Code^), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,     RestoreProtection) then
  begin
    Code^ := Value;
    VirtualProtect(Code, SizeOf(Code^), RestoreProtection, Ignore);
    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, Code, SizeOf(Code^));
  end;
end;

{--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure Patch(P: PAnsiChar);
var
  i: Integer;
  addr: PAnsiChar;
begin
  for i:= 0 to 31 do
  begin
    if (PCardinal(P)^ = $6850006a) and (PWord(P+8)^ = $E852) then
    begin
      inc(P, 10);
      if PInteger(P)^<0 then
      begin
        addr := P+4+PInteger(P)^;
        if PWord(addr)^=$25FF then
        begin
          PatchCodePtrUInt(Pointer(addr+2),cardinal(@RTLUnwindProc));
          exit;
        end;
      end;
    end else
      inc(P);
  end;
end;

{--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure PatchCallRtlUnWind;
asm
  mov eax,offset System.@HandleAnyException+200
  call Patch
end;

{--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure InitExceptionLogging;
begin
  oldRTLUnWindProc := RTLUnwindProc;
  RTLUnwindProc := @MyRtlUnwind;
  PatchCallRtlUnWind;
end;

{--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

initialization
  InitExceptionLogging;
end.
```

I'm not an expert of Delphi 5 (used by my enterprise), i hope that somebody will be able to help me.

Best regards !

P.S : U_Test is just a unit containing the "_MessageDlg" function which create and display a dialog message.

Comment: Much easier to use madExcept

Comment: madExcept seems interresting but a little bit too big for me, if i choose to do it like this, it's to limitate third party program or large implementation. But madExcept could be a solution if i don't find any responses. Thanks

Comment: It takes no time at all to add it in, it is proven to work, it has incredible breadth of capability, its stack tracing is superb. You have no chance of coming up with anything remotely as useful. And that's not meant personally. I know I could not do anything as wonderful as madExcept. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Being no expert of Delphi 5 as you claim, did you write that code yourself? I'd follow David's advise and replace it with madExcept. I'm not surprised you get AV's by patching adresses using some magic constants.

Comment: Looks like it was lifted from mORMot, by Synopse, @Lieven. The original code is more complicated; perhaps Joja oversimplified and accidentally deleted something important. Joja, does the original code compile and run correctly? That library's author can be seen around here. He may be able to help.

Comment: Sure, i used it as a reference but his solution cause me some errors, that's why i remove MemCheck for example. But yes, program run without problem, and even catch me errors. But crash just after ...

Comment: I also recommend from my heart MadExcept: www.madshi.net